# Gnuplot commands leave lots of unnecessary output texts in the terminal window

Tags: fortran, gnuplot, gfortran, fortran90

I prefer to call gnuplot for plotting from the main Fortran program file through the command:

```
call system('gnuplot heun_ode_solution_10_comparison.gnu;')
```

The content of the .gnu file is as follows:

```
#======================================

set term postscript color

unset key

unset grid

set title "Heun's ODE solver for 10 data samples" font "Helvetica Bold, 
24"

set xlabel "x" font "Helvetica Bold, 24"

set ylabel "y" font "Helvetica Bold, 24"

set xrange[0:4]

set yrange[0:80]

set xtics 0, 1, 4

set ytics 0, 15, 75

show term

plot "Heun_Solution_10.dat" using 1:3 smooth csplines lc rgb 'blue' lw 6 

title "True", "Heun_Solution_10.dat" using 1:2 smooth csplines lc rgb 
'red' lw 3 title "Heun"

set key top left

set term postscript eps enhanced "Helvetica" 26

set output 'heun_ode_solution_10_comparison.eps'

replot

#======================================
```

The program runs fine, plots also show up well. But the terminal window from where I had compiled and ran the fortran code gets filled with unnecessary output texts. This makes it difficult to scroll up the terminal window for cases when the program encounters any compiling error. I am pasting just first 5% of the output that I see in the terminal.

```
-----------------------
 terminal type is postscript landscape enhanced defaultplex \
   leveldefault color colortext \
   dashlength 1.0 linewidth 1.0 pointscale 1.0 butt noclip \
   nobackground \
   palfuncparam 2000,0.003 \
   "Helvetica" 14  fontscale 1.0 

%!PS-Adobe-2.0
%%Creator: gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 2
%%CreationDate: Mon May 21 21:57:04 2018
%%DocumentFonts: (atend)
%%BoundingBox: 50 50 554 770
%%Orientation: Landscape
%%Pages: (atend)
%%EndComments
%%BeginProlog
/gnudict 256 dict def
gnudict begin
%
% The following true/false flags may be edited by hand if desired.
% The unit line width and grayscale image gamma correction may also be changed.
%

----------------------
```

One can imagine the case if multiple gnu files are called from the Fortran file. How do I suppress these unnecessary output texts?

Comment: Where do you set a name of the output file for the first plot? Since you don't, the contents are not stored in the .eps file, but are shown in console.

Comment: @ Michael O. Thank you. I have now moved the command " set output 'heun_ode_solution_10_comparison.eps' " to the first line of the gnu file. This has removed 99% of the text. Now I get just this ouput, which I guess will remain?    terminal type is postscript landscape enhanced defaultplex \
   leveldefault color colortext \
   dashlength 1.0 linewidth 1.0 pointscale 1.0 butt noclip \
   nobackground \
   palfuncparam 2000,0.003 \
   "Helvetica" 14  fontscale 1.0

Comment: Have you `moved` it or `copied`? Because you have `two` plots here. When you add `replot` command, you are plotting once again.

Comment: I still get little unwanted output text. My .gnu file now is: set output 'heun_ode_solution_10_comparison.eps';
set term postscript color eps enhanced "Helvetica" 26;
unset key;
unset grid;
set title "Heun's ODE solver "Helvetica Bold, 24";
set xlabel "x" font "Helvetica Bold, 24";
set ylabel "y" font "Helvetica Bold, 24";
set xrange[0:4];
set yrange[0:80];
set xtics 0, 1, 4;
set ytics 0, 15, 75;
show term;
plot "Heun_Solution.dat" using 1:3 smooth csplines lc rgb 'blue' lw 6 title "Tr", "Heun_Solution.dat" using 1:2 smooth csplines lc rgb 'red' lw 3 title "Heu";
set key top left;

Comment: In your case `plot` should be a last command.

Comment: Problem fixed. The line: "show term" was resulting into those unwanted texts. Thanks Michael O.